# Multipage SVG with R

Tags: r, svg

When using `layout` in `lattice::xyplot` with `trellis.device` you can get several pages in a PDF:

```
trellis.device(pdf, file="myfile.pdf")
data(mtcars)
xyplot(hp~mpg|gear, data=mtcars, layout=c(1, 1))
dev.off()
```

I would like to use the same approach to get a [multi-page SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/multipage.html). I have tried `cairo::svg`, and the packages [`gridSVG`](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/gridsvg/), [`SVGAnnotation`](http://www.omegahat.org/SVGAnnotation/) and [`RSVGTipsDevice`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSVGTipsDevice/index.html) with no success: only the last page of the `trellis` object is saved.

Is there any solution using R code?

Thanks!

Comment: What would a multipage SVG look like? One file or separate ones?

Comment: This is an esoteric SVG feature, I doubt you really want to use it. Most viewers will just draw all pages one on another.

Comment: @James What I need is one file with several "images", as with the example with `trellis.device(pdf...`, in order to get something similar to a slideshow.

Comment: @mbq I did not know it. I thought it was a common feature. Anyway, is there an alternative approach to get something similar to a slideshow with SVG and R?

Comment: @Oscar Depends on the viewer; IMO the best idea is to make R generate a bunch of SVGs and than manually make some html page with javaScript doing the page switching.

Answer (score 3):

I finally decided to ask directy to [Paul Murrell](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/), the creator of grid and [gridSVG](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridSVG/index.html). He kindly provided some good advices and code which completely solved the problem with an approach similar to the advice from @mbq. I modified his code to write this function:

```
library(gridSVG)
library(XML)

animateTrellis <- function(object, file='animatedSVG.svg', 
                           duration=.1, step=2, show=TRUE){
  nLayers <- dim(object)
  stopifnot(nLayers>1)
  for (i in seq_len(nLayers)){
    p <- object[i]
    label <- p$condlevels[[1]][i]
    ##Create intermediate SVG files
    g <- grid.grabExpr(print(p, prefix=label),
                       name=label)
    if (i==1){ ## First frame
      ga <- animateGrob(g, group=TRUE,
                        visibility="hidden",
                        duration=duration, begin=step)
    } else if (i==nLayers){ ##Last Frame
      gg <- garnishGrob(g, visibility='hidden')
      ga <- animateGrob(gg, group=TRUE,
                        visibility="visible",
                        duration=duration, begin=step*(i-1))
    } else { ##any frame
      gg <- garnishGrob(g, visibility='hidden')
      gaV <- animateGrob(gg, group=TRUE,
                         visibility="visible",
                         duration=duration, begin=step*(i-1))
      ga <- animateGrob(gaV, group=TRUE,
                        visibility="hidden",
                        duration=duration, begin=step*i)
    }
    grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(ga)
    fich <- tempfile(fileext='.svg')
    gridToSVG(fich)

    ## Combine all
    if (i==1) {
      svgTop <- xmlParse(fich)
      nodeTop <- getNodeSet(svgTop,
                            "//svg:g[@id='gridSVG']",
                            c(svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"))[[1]]
    } else {
      svgChildren <- xmlParse(fich)
      node <- getNodeSet(svgChildren,
                         "//svg:g[@id='gridSVG']/*",
                         c(svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"))
      addChildren(nodeTop, node)
    }
    unlink(fich)
  }
  saveXML(svgTop, file=file)
  dev.off()
  if (show) browseURL(file)
  invisible(svgTop)
}
```

Then I can produce the SVG file with animation:

```
p <- xyplot(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length|Species, data=iris, layout=c(1, 1))
animateTrellis(p, file='iris.svg')
```